# What is faster to insert, update or delete MongoDB or SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

I am deciding between using MongoDB and MySQL for my next application. I'll use Elasticsearch for search queries so I don't care about this.

So in these 3 operations: insert, update and delete. Which one is faster, MongoDB or SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a recommendation question to me.

Comment: Well, it's not. I'm just asking which is faster :D

Comment: I edited out the word "NoSQL". MongoDB is not "NoSQL" because NoSQL is not the name of a technology — it's a marketing term. It's like asking which is faster, a motorcycle or "NotMotorcycle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inserting/updating/deleting an object, like a customer or order, then I would assume it would be slower to do it via SQL because that data would typically be normalized so you would need to split that object into it's normalized forms to insert.

The **real** answer is to load test the different tools based on your needs and see which works out for you but I suspect that either one will work well for you unless you're dealing with big, big data.

Comment: An "entity" is precisely *not split* across multiple tables.  That is what entity-relationship modeling does.

Comment: Bad term choice on my part, I'll update the reply to use a term that isn't overloaded.